# JVM Tuning on Container (Java 8)

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, jvm, amazon-ecs

We have recently moved our application stack to ECS-EC2 from EC2 and our plan is to move ECS-EC2 stack to production.
We have been facing problem in tuning the application on ECS-Container. We are using tomcat with our java web application. Dockerfile Configuration -

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.40-jre8
COPY checkout.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf
COPY context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf
COPY catalina.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin
ENV spring.profiles.active beta
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=beta"
RUN echo "export JAVA_OPTS=\"$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms12G -Xmx12G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:ConcGCThreads=5 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=60 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication\"" >> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
CMD ["sh", "-c", "catalina.sh run"]
```

Little about our application stack - We are using **r5.xlarge Instance type** having 4 services running inside ECS-EC2, and haven't provided the Hard Memory limit to task (We have only provided the soft memory to 2GB to each task).

**What we have done till now** -

I came across many post on internet across topic "**Nobody puts java on container**" [Example](https://www.adaltas.com/en/2017/10/28/nobody-puts-java-in-a-container/).
Hence for now upgraded to tomcat image *8.5.40 which is using open jdk "1.8.0_212"* (backward support to container).
But after using the above Dockerfile, when we run command `java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` inside the container it doesn't show same values for *JVM Tuning (MaxHeap, MinHeap, GC,ParallelGCThreads and Others.)* as provided by us in the  Dockerfile in **JAVA_OPTS** variable.

[image]

I tried similar thing in Docker Container locally but the same problem is occurring.

**How JVM Tuning on docker container based application is possible which is using Tomcat server (Java 8)? Any help will be appreciated.**

PS : Tomcat does print the JAVA_OPTS configuration in start-up of the `catalina.logs` file.

Comment: Who did the previous tuning?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen we use same tuning configuration, but it works with EC2, not containerized.

Comment: Try removing it to see how the JVM performs. Also consider upgrading to Java 11 which is much more container friendly.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I tried it removing except startup logs at ```catalina.logs```, no effect were there in output of ```java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal```. I have kept upgrading to Java 11 as last option cause it might have impact on internal dependency (need effort)
.

Answer (score 0):

When you run JVM inside docker you must use the following parameters to specify how much memory the virtual machine can take from the total available memory:

`-XX:+UseContainerSupport`

`-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0` (this flag says that the JVM can take max 70% from the docker image memory. By default this value is 25%)

Regarding GC, you have to see what JVM build you run on that image. Maybe that build doesn't allows you to specify the G1 GC (you can take a look here to see why https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148175)

Comment: ```UseContainerSupport``` is already enabled on Java 8u191+, Hence i'm using open jdk '1.8.0_212'. This variable is turned on by default. I have already tried giving this option but no luck. Any JVM tuning option (All which i given in docker file) is not taken into consideration on container (according to ```java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal```)

Comment: I also tried , Mentioning ``-XX:MaxRamPercentage`` but it's showing default 25.000000 via ``java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal``

Comment: I see in your Dockerfile that you have this ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=beta". Replace it with ENV JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=beta"

Comment: I tried but no luck, JAVA_OPTS is standard environment variable and till that line it consist no value.

Comment: When you execute java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal, then you start a new JVM with the default parameters. Try to execute this command on your docker image:

java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal and see the result.

If you see the correct settings, then add -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal to your JAVA_OPTS env variable